# C++ : Assign normal return value to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, return

How do I assign a normal return value of a function to a pointer?

For example, I want to assign the return value of this `static` member function:

```
int AnotherClass::getInt();
```

In the following expression :

```
// m_ipA is a private member of the class `Class`
int *m_ipA;
// Lots of things in between, then :
void Class::printOutput() {
    m_ipA = AnotherClass::getInt();
    // Some operations on m_iPA here, then
    // Print instructions here
}
```

Do I need to initialize `m_ipA` with the `new` keyword in the constructor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the real problem that you want to solve? I am not sure that you actually want to use that design... (i.e. keep a pointer in a class and have it initialized by a function that returns an integer

Comment: @ David Rodriguez: I want to use the temporary returned by the function instead of copying it and assigning it to a normal variable. Does that make sense to you? The benefit is not obvious in such a small snippet above, but I'm not planning to write small programs dealing with small piece of data all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
 m_ipA = new int; //do this also, if you've not allocated memory already.
*m_ipA = AnotherClass::getInt();
```

---

You may want to allocate memory in the constructor of the class as:

```
Class::Class() //constructor
{
  m_ipA = new int; //allocation
}

void Class::printOutput() 
{
    *m_ipA = AnotherClass::getInt();
}

Class::~Class() //destructor
{
  delete m_ipA; //deallocation
}
```

EDIT:

As MSalters reminded: when you've pointers in your class, then don't forget the copy ctor and assignment (Rule of Three).

Or mabye, you don't want *pointer to int*. I mean, the following might work for you:

```
int m_int; 

m_int = AnotherClass::getInt();
```

Notice `m_int` is not a pointer.

Comment: Don't forget the copy ctor and assignment (Rule of Three)

Comment: @MSalters: thanks for the reminder. I added that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Btw, given my case above and my objective to use temporary data (returned by AnotherClass::getInt() ) instead of copying it to a normal variable, do you think I'm on the right track?

Comment: @Tom: `getInt()` returns `int`. So you don't need to worry about it, since what you get at calling site is not "temporary". You've it as long as you've the variable `m_ipA`  holding the memory allocated to it. So the bottomline is : don't worry.

Comment: @Tom: Or mabye, you don't want pointer to int. I mean, `int m_int; m_int = AnotherClass::getInt();` should work for you. Notice `m_int` is not a pointer anymore. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

If `m_ipA` is not pointing to any valid memory location then you need to allocate memory like following:

```
m_ipA = new int(AnotherClass::getInt());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, your answer is highest ranked.

Answer (score 0):

```
m_ipA = new int;
*m_ipA = AnotherClass::getInt();

//Use m_ipA

delete m_ipA; //Deallocate memory, usually in the destructor of Class.
```

Or use some RAI such as an [auto_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/).  To forget about deallocating memory.

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't *have* to - just make sure you dereference the pointer!

`*m_ipA = AnotherClass::getInt();`
You really should though, if you intend to continually modify m_ipA